# PHP str_split with new line saved

Tags: php, string, file, loops

I would like to split my file content e.g

```
test
$
#
```

I use `str_split` and it works good except it does not save new lines.
New lines are saved like space `' '`.

My code:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);
$iterateableString = str_split($fileContent);
```

I want to iterate over each character but I want detect if some character is a new line too.

Thanks for advices!

Comment: Try `preg_split('/\h+/', $fileContent)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe :

```
foreach($iterateableString as $str){
  if(strstr($str, PHP_EOL)) {
   //Do something
  }
}
```